# Error SequelizeEagerLoadingError query and models

Tags: node.js, model, sequelize.js

I would like to execute this query sql :
SELECT u.name_user, u.firstname_user, u.email_user, u.school_user, j.date_joueur, j.infos_joueur, j.id_joueur, u.id_user FROM joueurs AS j, users AS u WHERE j.id_parent = 1 and j.id_user = u.id_user

I have 3 models Parents, Joueurs and Users.

Parents

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../database/db');
const Users = require('./Users');

var Parents = db.sequelize.define(
    'parents',
    {
        id_parent: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        timer_parent: {
            type: Sequelize.TIME
        },
        code_parent: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        },
       id_user: {
           type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
           references: {
                model: Users,
                key: 'id_user'
            }
       }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false
    }
)



module.exports = Parents
```

Joueurs

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../database/db');
const Users = require('./Users');
const Parents = require('./Parents');

var Joueurs = db.sequelize.define(
    'joueurs',
    {
        id_joueur: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        date_joueur: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE
        },
       id_user: {
           type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
           references: {
                model: Users,
                key: 'id_user'
            }
       },
       infos_joueur: {
           type: Sequelize.TEXT
       },
       id_parent: {
           type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
           references: {
               model: Parents,
               key: 'id_parent'
           }
       }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false
    }
)

Joueurs.associate = () => {
    Joueurs.belongsTo(Users, {
      foreignKey: 'id_user'
    })

    Joueurs.belongsTo(Parents, {
        foreignKey: 'id_parent'
      })
}


module.exports = Joueurs
```

and
Users

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../database/db');

module.exports = db.sequelize.define(
    'users',
    {
        id_user: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name_user: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        firstname_user: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        email_user: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        school_user: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        password_user: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false
    }
)
```

I try to execute this query but I have an error 'SequelizeEagerLoadingError':

```
Joueurs.findAll({
        attributes: [
            'date_joueur'
        ],
        include: [{
            model: Users,
            attributes: ['name_user']
        }]
    })
    .then(joueurs => {
        res.send(joueurs);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).json({ error: err});
    })
```

Can you help me please, i am searching this problem but i can't find
Thanks

Comment: Please provide the full error message.